# What kind of flag should I raise when I see garbage?

Tags: discussion, flags

I am wondering which flag to raise upon catching sight of something like this:

> Asdfghjkl lkjhgfdsa

Spam? It's not promoting anything.
Rude or abusive? It's not speaking ill of anything.
Not an answer? Of course it isn't but it isn't even anything meaningful.

BTW, is there archived examples for all kinds of flags? I am curious if there has ever been a question flagged as 'Blatantly Off-Topic'.

Comment: For your second question, there is data.stackexchange.com that allows you to query all information related to all sites, all info that's sharable, of course. Don't know for sure, but I think you can get close reason stats there. But the answer is "yes, of course there have been a lot of blatantly OT stuff that have been closed, and subsequently deleted".